# Office (mostly Word) keeps crashing on Windows 7 Lenovo

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, lenovo-laptop

My Office applications crash frequently.  I first noticed a problem with Word, then Outlook followed in by doing the same thing. It just says "not responding" and can't be interacted with.

This is almost a brand new, very clean Lenovo factory installation of Windows 7, with only the Lenovo preloaded software, and then Office 2010 installed by me afterwards.

I did a virus and malware and spyware scan, which had no results. I also repaired Office, and when that didn't work I completely reinstalled it, which didn't help either.

Word will crash right in the middle of something, and won't let you save or do anything other than close it. This happens every hour, or sometimes even more.

I'm looking for any suggestions more reasonable than "reinstall Windows 7".

Did a windows update, no fix there.

**Event log:**
Faulting application name: WINWORD.EXE, version: 14.0.4762.1000, time stamp: 0x4bae25cd
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec4aa8e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000028359
Faulting process id: 0x31d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccf6f32958503c
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 22d289a1-62f0-11e1-86fb-f0def1a68778

[image]

Comment: Any events in the event log?

Comment: Added the events log above.

Comment: Have you run the built-in diagnostics? http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/help/diagnose-and-repair-crashing-office-programs-by-using-office-diagnostics-HA001234076.aspx#BM2

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft just released this program.

Scan for Problems in Microsoft Outlook and MS Office products.

The Office Configuration Analyzer Tool (OffCAT) Analyzer Tool scans your MS-Office profiles to identify any potential issues.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36852

If you are a Help Desk professional, you can also save the report to file so that the report can be viewed in the Office Configuration Analyzer Tool on another client where the tool is installed. The Office Configuration Analyzer Tool 1.0 also includes a command-line version that can be used to collect an OffCAT scan without user intervention.

Comment: Good find - that identified a driver issue for me that's causing a crash.

Answer (score 0):

[Offical guide and tools to uninstall Office 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301)

[Unoffical cleanup tool for Office,](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/20894-Office-CleanUp-Tool-2003-2007-2010) you would run this batch file after uninstalling Office to clean up registry leftovers, may or may not cure your problem. Use at your own risk.

Comment: OP Indicates that he did a repair.

Answer (score 0):

Try running windows update and be sure to also include all updates for Microsoft Office.

To turn on automatic updates:

1. Click **Start**, and then click **Control Panel**.
2. Depending on which Control Panel view you use, Classic or Category, do one of the following:

   - Click **System**, and then click the **Automatic Updates** tab.
   - Click **Performance and Maintenance**, click **System**, and then click the **Automatic Updates** tab.
3. Click the option that you want. Make sure Automatic Updates is not turned off.

Microsoft provides a [video] that shows you how to update Windowscheck for  updates...

Comment: I did updates, nothing changed.